# How do you get GSON to omit null or empty objects and empty arrays and lists?

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using Gson and I am in a situation in which I have to shrink the size of certain Json strings.  I would like to do so by getting it to not put null objects, only empty values, and empty lists and arrays into the Json string.

Is there a straightforward way to do that?

Let me clarify a bit:  I want everything that says:  emptyProp:{} or emptyArray:[] to be skipped.  I want any object that only contains properties that are empty to be skipped.

Comment: Isn't that the default behavior?

Comment: No it puts in empty arrays, etc.

Comment: "it puts in empty arrays, etc." -- ??? I recommend posting a complete minimal example of what you're talking about.  The docs say, "While serialization, a null field is skipped from the output" (but I wouldn't be surprised if this isn't correct).

Comment: Then I am somewhat confused: "to not put null objects, _only_ empty values..." What does "only" mean here? Do you want empty values etc included or do you not want them included?

Comment: I want empty values, such as empty strings excluded.

Answer (score 33):

Null values are excluded by default as long as you don't set serializeNulls() to your GsonBuilder.

A way for empty lists is to create a JsonSerializer

```
class CollectionAdapter implements JsonSerializer<List<?>> {
  @Override
  public JsonElement serialize(List<?> src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
    if (src == null || src.isEmpty()) // exclusion is made here
      return null;

    JsonArray array = new JsonArray();

    for (Object child : src) {
      JsonElement element = context.serialize(child);
      array.add(element);
    }

    return array;
  }
}
```

Then register it

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Collection.class, new CollectionAdapter()).create();
```

Comment: Are you sure the above code is correct? Is doesn't seem to affect anything when I try it?

Comment: Yeah, this didn't work for me as well until I changed the `Collection<?>` to `List<?>` and then it worked as the should

Comment: I also added another class that implements JsonSerializer<Map>. This handles empty object {} in the JSON

Comment: @mdev How can we extend this to ignore empty strings and empty lists?

Comment: this should be registered for List.class instead of collection. Otherwise you'll get cast exception with other collections

Answer (score 2):

According to [PomPom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17089654/7306276) a HashMap can serialized via:

```java
class MapAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Map<?, ?>> {
        @Override
        public JsonElement serialize(Map<?, ?> src, Type typeOfSrc,JsonSerializationContext context) {
            if (src == null || src.isEmpty())
                return null;
            JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
            for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : src.entrySet()) {
                obj.add(entry.getKey().toString(), context.serialize(entry.getValue()));
            }
        return obj;
        }
    }
```