# GSON deserialization ignore empty objects in list

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, gson

A client has decided to start sending empty `JSON` objects at the end of arrays (to help their caching `facepalm`) but this has caused a whole bunch of unexpected behaviour in my app.

For example this is the data I am being sent...

```
[{object}, {object}, {}, {object}]
```

I currently use `GSON` to deserialize data sent from the server. I have been looking into type adapters to filter out these empty objects, however I am not fully sure how to implement the filtering. Any ideas on how to skip empty objects using `GSON`?

Comment: Are you having problems with the actual deserialization, or are you having problems after the parsing is complete and objects have been created?

Comment: The parsing was correct ...  I just was wondering if there was a way to easily ignore empty objects....

Comment: Can you simply iterate the resulting object items and remove the ones that have missing data?

Comment: Yeah that is essentially what I ended up doing ... was kind of hoping to do it through the deserialization process but just did it post deserialization.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue ... I had to make a `TypeAdapterFactory` that set empty objects to `null` then filtered out the nulls from the resulting list.

Here is my `TypeAdapterFactory`

```
private static class EmptyCheckTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> type) {

        // We filter out the EmptyCheckTypeAdapter as we need to check this for emptiness!
        if (Story.class.isAssignableFrom(type.getRawType())) {
            final TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
            final TypeAdapter<JsonElement> elementAdapter = gson.getAdapter(JsonElement.class);
            return new EmptyCheckTypeAdapter<>(delegate, elementAdapter).nullSafe();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public class EmptyCheckTypeAdapter<T> extends TypeAdapter<T> {

        private final TypeAdapter<T> delegate;
        private final TypeAdapter<JsonElement> elementAdapter;

        public EmptyCheckTypeAdapter(final TypeAdapter<T> delegate,
                                     final TypeAdapter<JsonElement> elementAdapter) {
            this.delegate = delegate;
            this.elementAdapter = elementAdapter;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(final JsonWriter out, final T value) throws IOException {
            this.delegate.write(out, value);
        }

        @Override
        public T read(final JsonReader in) throws IOException {
            final JsonObject asJsonObject = elementAdapter.read(in).getAsJsonObject();
            if (asJsonObject.entrySet().isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }
            return this.delegate.fromJsonTree(asJsonObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, filtered out the `null`s using the following code

```
myDto.stories.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
```

Comment: Not optimal to filter the list after the fact, is it possible to tell GSON to not add the null element to the list in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942118/how-do-you-get-gson-to-omit-null-or-empty-objects-and-empty-arrays-and-lists)

```
class CollectionAdapter implements JsonSerializer<Collection<?>> {

     @Override
     public JsonElement serialize(Collection<?> src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
     if (src == null || src.isEmpty()) // exclusion is made here
        return null;

     JsonArray array = new JsonArray();

     for (Object child : src) {
         JsonElement element = context.serialize(child);
         array.add(element);
     }

     return array;
   }
}
```

Then register it

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Collection.class, new CollectionAdapter()).create();
```

Comment: I do not need to serialize data ... can I do something similar for deserialization?

Comment: Yup, this is not at all deserialization.