# GSON: convert JSON with null array field into empty array

Tags: android, json, gson

How can I say to GSON that if a JSON with an array field has NULL value, it has to create an empty array instead of setting a null?

are there any properties or Flags available for this?

Comment: what about this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17089654/4310784

Comment: can you post class (if any) which you are using to de/serialize..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do some workaround before you pass your json to Gson.

```
String currentKeyTags = "\"KeyTags\":null";
String expectedKeyTags = "\"KeyTags\":[]";

String jsonArrayString= jsonArray.toString()
                        .replaceAll(currentKeyTags, expectedKeyTags);
```

Now:

```
 Gson gson=new Gson();
     Type listType = new TypeToken<List<?>>() {
                }.getType();
    List<?> lists = gson.fromJson(jsonArrayString, listType);
```

Comment: I was looking for a Flag, not  a hack. But I'll try it. Thanks!